# From Tableau to Google Sheets

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to export Tableau figures to Google Sheets?

(I'm populating a spreadsheet that I'd like to keep in Google Sheets with data that I've manipulated in Tableau where I do a lot of data-cleaning, data-joining, etc)

Comment: You could export your manipulated data via a crosstab to Excel, then paste it into Google Sheets, or are you looking for automation?

Comment: Have you tied exporting to CSV ('download crosstab' or 'view data'>'Download all rows to text file') and uploading to google drive ?

Comment: @BenP I'm looking for automation - any ideas?

Comment: Not something I have experience with, but the following link may help: https://community.tableau.com/thread/147641

Comment: I would like this automation too. Looks like there is a way to import data from Google Sheets to Tableau but I need to another way around.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting as a CSV from Worksheet > Export > Data.

That should take all the data and put it into rows. You may have to format some parts yourself as there isn't an automated method of doing this. From this you can open the .csv file as a Google Sheet.